# Creating wrinkles on stretched sail

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to create a square sail that is stretched on its corners, to create realistic wrinkling similar to the sample image attached. I've initiated a model which consists of a simple plane. I've subdivided the mesh of the part and have attempted to do this using shape keys to displace the corners to create catenary curves on the edges of the square. I then added cloth physics but the end result looks nothing like what I need. I've tried playing around with the settings of the cloth physics but so far to no avail.
I attach the blend file of my model to Blend-Exchange. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image: Sample image]
.[image: Attempted result]

Answer (score 2):

first of all i would recommend using quads for cloth physics.

Second i would start with a very simple shape (without hole) and a shape-VG group to control what you wanna have.

So select the corner vertices, add them to a VG. Give the cloth modifier that VG as shape.

Then select the same (!) vertices of one corner to one hook empty. Do the same to the other corners.
Animate the hook empties.
Make sure that your cloth modifier is after all hook modifiers.

Try first with default settings like silk, denim and so on and check the result.

Then as a starting point you get something like this:

[image]

Hint: i turned field weight gravity to 0 for this.

For the hole, tbh i would use another plane with hole and use surface deform modifier on that "simple plane without hole" to make your life much easier.